# Input lag on R-Go Split Break Ergonomic Keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I'm experiencing input lag with the R-Go Split Break Ergonomic Keyboard on Ubuntu 20.04. Does anyone know how to fix that?

R-Go support suggested using wayland. This did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought the R-Go Split keyboard and had the same issue. In another thread I found someone recommending this repository: https://github.com/Ckath/mergeinputs which works very well for me.
However, I had to adapt the example line from:

```
mergeinputs /dev/input/by-id/*-kbd
```

to:

```
mergeinputs /dev/input/by-path/*-kbd
```

Hope that helps!